# Why is the undo function disabled with Worksheet_Change event?

Tags: excel, vba

I use a macro to print the timestamp in column AJ when anything in the range A:AH is changed, but it disables the undo function in Excel. I am also using another worksheet_change event that auto capitalizes text, but it doesn't disable the undo functionality. Why does this code disable undo and is there any way around it? Thanks for any help

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' Code to print timestamp in Column AJ following a change in a corresponding row
    Dim WorkRng As Range, row As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Intersect(Range("A:AH"), Target)
    If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rng In WorkRng
                row = rng.row
                If Not rng.Value = "" Then
                    Cells(row, "AJ").Value = Now
                    Cells(row, "AJ").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                Else
                    Cells(row, "AJ").Value = Now
                    Cells(row, "AJ").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                End If
            Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually any macro that writes to cells resets the undo list, including event handlers. Can you show your `worksheet_change` handler that doesn't do it?

Comment: Put another way, any event that changes the worksheet destroys the Undo stack.  See item 11 in https://trumpexcel.com/vba-events/